# SQL iterate over information_schema.columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, iteration

I have a SQL Server table with 100 columns. I would like to do this to each column:

```
UPDATE 2011INFODATA
SET [Attribute_Code_1] = ltrim(rtrim(Attribute_Code_1))
WHERE len(ltrim(rtrim(Attribute_Code_1))) > 0
```

My question is how I can use the informatin_schema.columns to dynamically generate or insert the various column names into the above SQL?

I could of course do it by hand for each column and get the same result. But that would be no fun and I want to use this same sql for many tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something along these lines will do it.

```
DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(max)
SET @Sql = '';
SELECT @Sql = @Sql + '
    UPDATE 2011INFODATA
    SET ' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) + ' = ltrim(rtrim(' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) + '))
    WHERE len(ltrim(rtrim(' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) + '))) > 0'
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE TABLE_NAME = '2011INFODATA' AND DATA_TYPE LIKE '%char'
EXEC sp_executesql @Sql
```

Edit: updated sample SQL to incorporate helpful comments from @billinkc, @Martin Smith, @Aaron Bertrand.

Comment: You might be interested in a filter to your query along the lines of WHERE DATA_TYPE = 'varchar' to ensure you aren't trying operations on data types that don't make sense (ints) or will have no effect (char)

Comment: RE: Inadvertent SQL injection if you use `QUOTENAME` you should be safe AFAIK.

Comment: Always prefix stored procedure calls with `EXEC` or `EXECUTE`. This code will fail on the last line, because you can only leave off the `EXEC` if the stored procedure call is the first statement in a batch.

Comment: OK, Thank You. I see what is going on here. How is the iteration taking place? When I execute this will it run 100 times if the 2011INFODATA table has 100 columns?

Comment: This will not work as Column_Name will return a result set, in order for this to work a cursor could be used.

Comment: @opensourcechris I'm not sure what you mean. `COLUMN_NAME` is a column of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`, not a result set. This statement will update `@Sql` once for each column of the target table